# change time field to select list

Tags: datetime

I am using a date field in a content type.
I want to make it work similar to the date/time input in facebook events.
When I use date field as a Pop-up calendar it appears like this:

[image]

For *date input* it is fine as it is – but for the *time imput* I would prefer to have a drop down field (select list) with the *date input* as pop-up calender here. When I try this...

```
$dropdown_time_array = array('12:00 pm','12:15 pm','12:30 pm','12:45 pm', );
if($form_id == $form_id_node){
$form['field_date'] = array(     
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#default_value' => '1',        
     '#options' => $dropdown_time_array,
  ); 
}
```

…it actually overrides the whole field – including the *date input*.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the Pop-up date widget to use wvega-timepicker depending whether you're using a Date field or custom module there are different ways of using it.

Comment: I did the same, I used Date Popup Timepicker module https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_timepicker and used wvega-timepicker in it. Thanks Collin.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to find out what you need to type is to insert a debug statement.

Enable the devel module and then just before the code you have added above add in 
    dpm($form);

This will show you the structure of the array.  You will need to change your code to something like this, but please don't just copy what I did, it's not exactly right - get the actual name of the sub-field from looking at the array (if you are not sure, post your debug output).

```
$form['field_date']['time'] = array(
```

Once you have the answer, of course you remove the debug code and turn of devel again.